# Do I need to specify Required if I've already specified Key?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, data-annotations

With Code First Data Annotations, if I have already specified the Key attribute for a property will that also make it Required or do I need both?

Basically, if I want to make sure my primary key gets populated, do I need to do this:

```
    [Key]
    [Required] 
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } //internal id
```

Or will this suffice:

```
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } //internal id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No by default Key is required, it's a first form of normalization and a row without a value for primary key can not be inserted, updated or deleted.